# Error: Webpack 2 can't resolve babel-loader

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, webpack-2, babel-loader

I run into the following error message when tried to set up webpack 2 with babel:

`ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in 'path_to_project_dir'`

The configuration file following the webpack 2 docs:

```
const path = require('path')

const config = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
        ],
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ["es2015"]
        },
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      'node_modules',
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    ],
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx'],
  }
}

module.exports = config
```

I have the following dev dependencies in my packages.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
  "babel-loader": "^6.4.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
  "path": "^0.12.7",
  "webpack": "^2.2.1",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1"
},
```

My node and npm versions are:

```
node 7.7.1
npm 4.4.1
```

My OS is macOS Sierra

What could be the source of this error message, and how should I solve it. I tried a lot of tutorials and blog posts to find a solution but none of them worked.

Comment: you have run `npm install` right?

Comment: Yes I did, I just created the dependencies using `yarn add *dependency* --dev`

Strange thing: now I deleted node_modules and yarn.lock then run the `yarn` command and now it works.

I'd still be curious what could have caused this dependency issue, to avoid it in the future.

Comment: @AdamWolski thanks for sparkling the idea to re-install the node modules, **likely it's a dependency issue**, did the same in other `webpack 2` setups I tried and had the same issue and this way they work as well.

Comment: I managed to identify the source of this error, most likely it's not related to `webpack 2` or `babel`, actually it is only happening when using **atom editor's term3 package's terminal**. Somehow it doesn't install the npm modules correctly. When using the default Terminal it works

Comment: run `npm install babel-loader -D ` again

Answer (score 3):

I investigated the `node_modules` directory and found a lot of dependencies missing. I deleted the `node_modules` directory and `yarn.lock` file and from a new Terminal window ran the `yarn` command.

It worked, installed all the dependencies, and webpack 2 & babel worked as it should.

As originally I installed the npm modules with `atom editor's term3 terminal`,
I tried to do the same reinstall there, however it produced missing dependencies as originally.

**So the error has been caused by the term3 package of atom**

**Solution:** use the standard terminal, and DON'T use the terminal provided by the term3 package of atom

Comment: I also had to end up upgrading npm to the latest version, although this appears to be an unrelated issue.